# Popup window without address & menu bar on click of hyperlinkfield in gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am developing a screen in c# dot net where i have a search screen which contains a hyperlink field containing some querystring values, on clik of hyperlink field i have to open a pop up window which is working fine however i dont want adress bar or menu items to be displayed in pop up window also size should be specific, can anyone please tell me how to achive it.

I am using below code however its only changing size of window and not hiding menu etc moreover first pop up window gets loaded in full size and then gets changed to size i have specified.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="FileName" DataTextField="FileName"
Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="javascript:var NewWin=window.open
('abc.aspx?EMPId={0}',null,'width=800,height=200,top=100,left=100,scrollbars=no,
directories=no,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no');"HeaderText="EMPId">

</asp:HyperLinkField>
```

Also, i could use a linkbutton where this pop up window is working fine however i have a requirement of adding querystring in rowdatabound of grid to URL which gets fired on click on my linkbutton and pop up window gets open however i am not able to do so by using below code.

```
protected void grdDisplayResult_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
HyperLink hyperlink = (HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
Label lblRowNumber = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblRowNum"));
hyperlink.NavigateUrl += "&RowNum=" + lblRowNumber.Text;
}
}
```

if i get solution for any of them it would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling a javascript function & passing parameters to it. You can  find your control server side using `RowDataBound` event of gridview & attach a client side event to open popup. There you pass parameters to your function using `Eval` & open a popup with your desired query string values. Something like this
On aspx

```
    <script language="text/javascript">
     function OpenPopup(id,name)
     {
          window.open('myWindow.aspx?id='+id+'&name='+name,'_blank',width=800,height=200,top=100,left=100,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,directories=no,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,url=no');
     }
     </script>
```

On server side inside `RowDataBound` event of your gridview

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        { 
          LinkButton myLinkBtn= (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("yourControlid");
          if(myLinkBtn !=null)
          {
              myLinkBtn.Attributes.add('onclick','javascript:OpenPopup('"+ Eval(e.row.DataItem,"yourDbField1")+ "','"+ Eval(e.row.DataItem,"yourDbField2")+ "');return false;");
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you can use link button instead of hyper link.

Comment: Hi link button is working for me and it opening popup window as i want however i have a problem with linkbutton where i am not able to add another(non database value) querystring which i could do as in hyperlinkfield.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you do not have to do this in RowDataBound. you can do something like

Comment: You do not have to do this in RowDataBound. you can do something like this. Then in the OnCommand, get the RowNum, then you Redirect the response to the new page with the querystring. I assume the lblRowNum is bound to a field. Even no, you can still pass the .Text.

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderImageUrl="~/Images/information.png" >
  <ItemTemplate>
     <div>     
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDelete" runat="server" OnCommand="lbtnDelete_OnCommand" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RowNum") %>' >Delete</asp:LinkButton>
   </div>    
  </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

Answer (score 0):

Try using `HTMLAnchor` instead of `asp:Hyperlink`

**Grid:**

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Options">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="aFooLink" runat="server">
        ClickMeDamnit</a>
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

**CodeBehind:**

```
protected void grdDisplayResult_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink aFooLink = (HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
        aFooLink.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('abc.aspx?EMPId=0','window','toolbar=no, menubar=no, resizable=yes,location=no,center:no;height=200px,width=300px,Top=1500,left=1500;statusbar:no;');");            
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Hi Mayank,Thanks for your reply however i have to bind data in this column which ic coming from database...would it work for it as well.